# Find all occurrences of substring in string

Tags: c#

I have a text file that includes things such as the following:

```
_vehicle_12 = objNull;
if (true) then
{
  _this = createVehicle ["Land_Mil_Guardhouse", [13741.654, 2926.7075, 3.8146973e-006], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_12 = _this;
  _this setDir -92.635818;
  _this setPos [13741.654, 2926.7075, 3.8146973e-006];
};
```

I want to find all occurrences between `{` and `};` and assign the following strings:

```
string direction = "_this setDir" value, in example _vehicle_12 it would mean that:
string direction = "-92.635818";

string position = "_this setPos" value, in example _vehicle_12 it would be:
string position = "[13741.654, 2926.7075, 3.8146973e-006]";
```

I have multiple occurrences of these types and would like to figure out the best way each time the `{ };` occurs to set direction and position and move onto the next occurrence.

The following code can read the string (that holds the file in a large string) and it finds the first occurence fine, however I would like to adapt it to finding every occurrence of the { and };

```
string alltext = File.ReadAllText(@file);
string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re2 = "(\\{.*?\\})"; // Curly Braces 1

Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(alltext);
if (m.Success)
{
    String cbraces1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("Found vehicle: " + cbraces1.ToString() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us the code that you've been working on to solve this problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you!  Code has been added.

Comment: Regex.Match will accept a starting position.

Comment: @Dan-o could you elaborate more?

Comment: also, Regex.Matches will return a collection of all the peices that match your pattern.

Comment: Answer was:

            `
            foreach (Match itemMatch in r.Matches(alltext))
            {
                string match = itemMatch.Groups[1].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Found vehicle: " + match + "\n");
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Think of a regex that might work
2. Test it.
3. If it does not work, modify and return to step 2.
4. You have a working regex :-)

To get you started:

```
\{\n([0-z\[\]" ,-\.=]+;\n)+\}
```

should return the individual lines inside the curly braces.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to accept your reply as an answer, but it's certainly what I used, thank you!